# おく for "home country"?

Tags: words

I've been asked a couple of times by Japanese where my "おく" was, and I just respond to where my country of origin (the answer is what they were expecting so I guess I have the right notion of what it means).

I can't actually find おく in the dictionary referring to country. Is it short for something (like お国)?

Comment: Can you recall the full context of what you were asked? Was it something like 「おくはどこですか」or something similar?

Comment: Yes, could you please share the whole sentence?

Comment: one time was simply something like "えと。。おく？" and recently something like　"~~~おくは？"

Comment: @Tyress Are you sure you didn't hear に?

Answer (score 3):

おくに

> ejje.weblio.jp --  お国を英語に訳すと ⇒ くに
>
> 用例
>
> - お国はどちらですか. Where [What country] do you come from?
> - お国では皆さまお変わりもありませんか. Is everybody at home well?

Heimat

For some reason they pronounced the に in おくに very weakly. I'm not sure why. (Local dialect?)

In speech, most ppl are already saying it without the WA as: お国どちらですか? -- and i suppose this sounds a bit like おくんどちらですか? --or-- おく<sub>ん</sub>どちらですか?

The vowel in に of おくに is more schwa-like than [i] or [i:] of English or German, for sure.  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schwa